# ufunc 'subtract' not supported for the input types....inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ufunc, xpress-optimizer

```
import numpy as np
import xpress as xp
p = xp.problem ("Problem")

x = np.empty(6+1).tolist()
constraint = np.array([140,100,110,100,120,100], dtype = xp.npvar)
for i in range(6):
    x[i] = x[i] <= constraint
    p.addConstraint(x[i])
    

y = np.empty(6+1).tolist()
diff =np.array([120,100,90,120,110], dtype = xp.npvar)
for n in range(6):
    if(y[0]):
        y[n] == x[n] - 100
    y[n] == x[n] + y[n] - diff
    p.addConstraint(y[n])
```

so i was trying to run this code using numpy and xpress and after that I got this error

ufunc 'subtract' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

I dont know what to do right after this, i tried using tempt variables, or declaring them int... and still doesnt change a thing

Comment: Full error message please

Comment: Exception has occurred: TypeError X
ufunc 'subtract' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Untitled-1.py", line 17, in <module>
    y[n] == x[n] - 100

Comment: You need to check what `x` contains at this point.  It was created using a `xp.npvar` dtype array, which I know nothing about.  Normally these `unsupported types` errors identify the problem dtypes, but I don't see that here.  I don't know if that's because of `xp`.

Comment: thanks, thats the thing im a beginner here using xpress and numpy

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do? Maybe show the mathematical model of the problem you want to create? Your code looks a bit fishy: `x` is created as a list of uninitialized elements using `xp.empty()`. Then you do `x[i] = x[i] <= constraints` which seems to use those uninitialized values. Moreover, since `constraints` is not a scalar, after this statement `x[i]` will be an *array* of constraints. Then, `constraints` is defined to have type `npvar` but its data are all plain numbers. Are these supposed to be variable indices?
As you can see, a lot of things don't add up.